# Can't Update Data on mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, crud

I was trying to update data on mysql but it always show me "Data gagal update" is the something wrong? here my buku-update.php

```
<?php
        if ( isset($_POST['update'])) {
            $koneksi = dbConnect();
                if ($koneksi->connect_errno == 0) {
                // Bersihkan data
                    $Kode_Buku = $koneksi->escape_string($_POST['Kode_Buku']);
                    $Judul = $koneksi->escape_string($_POST['Judul']);
                    $Edisi = $koneksi->escape_string($_POST['Edisi']);
                    $Kode_Penerbit = $koneksi->escape_string($_POST['Kode_Penerbit']);
                    //Menyusun SQL
                    $sql = "UPDATE buku SET Judul='$Judul',Edisi='$Edisi',Kode_Penerbit='$Kode_Penerbit' WHERE Kode_Buku='$Kode_Buku'";
                    $res = $koneksi->query($sql);
                    if ($res) {
                      if ($koneksi->affected_rows > 0) { // jika ada update data
                        ?>Data Berhasil diupdate.
                        <br>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary mt-3" href="buku.php" role="button">Kembali</a>
                        <?php

                      } else { //Jika sql sukses tapi tidak ada yang berubah
                        ?>Data Berhasil diupdate tetapi tidak ada perubahaan.
                        <br>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary mt-3" href="buku.php" role="button">Kembali</a>
                        <?php
                        }
                      } else { //gagal query
                        ?>Data Gagal diupdate
                        <br>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary mt-3" href="buku.php" role="button">Kembali</a>
                        <?php
                      }
                    } else
                      echo "Koneksi Dengan Database Gagal";
                  }
  ?>
```

[My Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5TPU.png)

Thanks all

Comment: Like so many people, you're not bothering to ask MySQL what the problem is. Instead of displaying some generic error message, display `$koneski->error`

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bd_buku`.`buku`, CONSTRAINT `buku_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Kode_Penerbit`) REFERENCES `penerbit` (`Kode_Penerbit`))

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to answer if you could output the last error or explain what happens.

Something like this might help.

```
} else { //gagal query
?>
      Data Gagal diupdate
      <?php echo "<strong>" . $koneksi->error() . "</strong>"; ?>
      <br>
      <a class="btn btn-primary mt-3" href="buku.php" role="button">Kembali</a>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bd_buku`.`buku`, CONSTRAINT `buku_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Kode_Penerbit`) REFERENCES `penerbit` (`Kode_Penerbit`))